# Rviz odometry color circles with different sizes - what do they represent

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I process a bag file with rtabmap and rgbd odometry.

The odometry (/rtabmap/odom) in rviz shows colored (purple and yellow) dots in different sizes.

Can someone tell me what they mean?

The closest I got was in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JgP2X-ARj-A) video, but the yellow circles there refer to something else, I think.

Thanks,
Avner

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314289/rviz-odometry-color-circles-with-different-sizes---what-do-they-represent/) by [Avner](https://answers.ros.org/users/36789/avner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These appear to be PoseWithCovariance messages being displayed in arrow mode. They will probably make more sense if you set them to be displayed as axes using the drop down in RVIZ.

The yellow blobs you can see are actually ellipses and they describe the angular uncertainty of the pose estimate while the purple ellipsoid in the centre describes the position uncertainty of the pose estimate.

Hope this helps.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-31**:
Link to (one of the) package(s) that provides such a plugin: [rviz_plugin_covariance](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz_plugin_covariance).

Apparently part of RViz since [ros-visualization/rviz#1099](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/pull/1099).